# How to change system language in RStudio?

Tags: rstudio

I change my system language to English both:
1) In R, R console: language = en
2) For any R script file : Sys.setlocale(category = "LC_ALL", locale = "english")
But when I started a new R markdown file in R Studio, the date is still not in English.
Anyone can help solve this issue? Thank you.

Updated with sessionInfo()

```
R version 3.4.4 (2018-03-15)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] tmaptools_1.2-3        tmap_1.11-1            countrycode_1.00.0    
etc. 26 packages attached            

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] readxl_1.0.0       backports_1.1.2    osmar_1.1-7        plyr_1.8.4         lazyeval_0.2.1    
etc. 114 loaded via a namespace
```

Comment: I think you need to give more detail.  What platform are you on?  How do you insert the date?

Comment: Platform: RStudio. Created new file: R markdown. In the R mark down file, everything is in English, except the date in the headline.

Comment: Show us the source for a (minimal) document that has this problem, and show us `sessionInfo()`.

Comment: Updated with my sessionInfo(), will post the source for a minimal document as soon as I figure this out.